# Tokens lost when XCM MessageProcessor "Processing failed"?

Tags: xcm, xcmv3

Right after Kusama got upgraded to 1.0,
all the upward messages from Mangata started to fail on Kusama with the following error:

```
messageQueue.ProcessingFailed
Message discarded due to an error in the MessageProcessor (usually a format error). 
id: [u8;32]
0x90fd8ab8327d393862fd5c559193238a363746c1044712eda15334310a195e20
origin: PolkadotRuntimeParachainsInclusionAggregateMessageOrigin
Ump
Ump: PolkadotRuntimeParachainsInclusionUmpQueueId
Para
Para: u32
2,110
error: FrameSupportMessagesProcessMessageError
Unsupported
```

I've been investigating, and I can not find where those tokens are now.
Ive checked the balance of the sovereign account, and the tokens did not change +-5 blocks when the tx failed.

> Sovereign account: F7fq1irK3J8tbBHJ2aeXJMAZTEXkoyPWPNJL1TTMhsjo6GZ.

We have a collection of failed XCMs since then, can you help us find where those KSMs are? We would like to return them to the legit users :)

+INFO:
https://mangatax.subscan.io/xcm_message/kusama-9402eac38ea75f98ad112a497da35e7f86c063c9

Failed Tx: 0xa10284009a89082c3ecc32a28b1ad69e8c69960b48a80fbf20ede17189995d8b4a1730770108f66dda5dc3e844c874f569632777da2fcc4f3d313ed1d230b3d5e2edcdc858a7b693366925bc322f41b039f6b86834c1195c2ced4e85ce0016527fd60ed7884401180032000400000000502c0634300000000000000000000003010101005ccce931d9f8465e3628d772f33cf4e8b4173505637fa8b96b5dccc13902c81201028c864700

Failed XCMs:
https://mangatax.subscan.io/xcm_message?address=&fromChain=2110&toChain=all&startDate&endDate&startBlock=&endBlock=&timeType=date&result=failed&protocol=all

Thankss!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the real relaychain KSM has not been lost. As you can see, "the tokens of sovereign account did not change +-5 blocks when the tx failed". It was still in the sovereign account of parachain(2110), under the control of the parachain((2110). **What lost is only the mapped assets within the parachain. You can use governance (Or other accounts with sufficient permissions) to mint the lost mapped KSM on your parachain and allocate it to the users who lost their assets.**

*What happened* when you reserve transfer the mapped KSM from parachain to Kusama(relaychain) ?

Steps:

On your parachain (Mangata)

1. XCM(Withdraw&InitiateReserveWithdraw instructions) destroy the mapped KSM, [TokenId=4 on Mangata](https://github.com/mangata-finance/mangata-node/blob/v0.31.0/runtime/common/src/lib.rs#L88)
2. Send to relaychain

On Relaychain (Failed)

1. Withdraw KSM from parachain(Mangata) sovereign account
2. BuyExecution and then deposit the assets to the receiver.

So the current situation is the mapped KSM on parachain is destroyed, but the xcm was not executed on Kusama, the real KSM is still in the parachain sovereign account.

You could mint the mapped KSM on your parachain for the users. Or you can transfer the real KSM from the parachain sovereign account to users on Kusama (Sending XCM from parachain through governance/ROOT to Kusama to control sovereign account).

Comment: That makes sense :)  
Thanks for the clarification!